# Wrong Leave deduction in Payslip odoo

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

I tried to generate payslip for an employee. An Employee has taken half day leave(0.5) but while calculating payslip its auto filled as 1.

From the code that is already in the module hr_payroll.py, It looks like the following

```
 def get_worked_day_lines(self, cr, uid, contract_ids, date_from, date_to, context=None):
        """
        @param contract_ids: list of contract id
        @return: returns a list of dict containing the input that should be applied for the given contract between date_from and date_to
        """
        def was_on_leave(employee_id, datetime_day, context=None):
            res = False
            day = datetime_day.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
            holiday_ids = self.pool.get('hr.holidays').search(cr, uid, [('state','=','validate'),('employee_id','=',employee_id),('type','=','remove'),('date_from','<=',day),('date_to','>=',day)])
            if holiday_ids:
                res = self.pool.get('hr.holidays').browse(cr, uid, holiday_ids, context=context)[0].holiday_status_id.name
            return res

        res = []
        for contract in self.pool.get('hr.contract').browse(cr, uid, contract_ids, context=context):
            if not contract.working_hours:
                #fill only if the contract as a working schedule linked
                continue
            attendances = {
                 'name': _("Normal Working Days paid at 100%"),
                 'sequence': 1,
                 'code': 'WORK100',
                 'number_of_days': 0.0,
                 'number_of_hours': 0.0,
                 'contract_id': contract.id,
            }
            leaves = {}
            day_from = datetime.strptime(date_from,"%Y-%m-%d")
            day_to = datetime.strptime(date_to,"%Y-%m-%d")
            nb_of_days = (day_to - day_from).days + 1
            for day in range(0, nb_of_days):
                working_hours_on_day = self.pool.get('resource.calendar').working_hours_on_day(cr, uid, contract.working_hours, day_from + timedelta(days=day), context)
                if working_hours_on_day:
                    #the employee had to work
                    leave_type = was_on_leave(contract.employee_id.id, day_from + timedelta(days=day), context=context)
                    if leave_type:
                        #if he was on leave, fill the leaves dict
                        if leave_type in leaves:
                            leaves[leave_type]['number_of_days'] += 1.0
                            leaves[leave_type]['number_of_hours'] += working_hours_on_day
                        else:
                            leaves[leave_type] = {
                                'name': leave_type,
                                'sequence': 5,
                                'code': leave_type,
                                'number_of_days': 1.0,
                                'number_of_hours': working_hours_on_day,
                                'contract_id': contract.id,
                            }
                    else:
                        #add the input vals to tmp (increment if existing)
                        attendances['number_of_days'] += 1.0
                        attendances['number_of_hours'] += working_hours_on_day
            leaves = [value for key,value in leaves.items()]
            res += [attendances] + leaves
        return res
```

I am not sure whether this is where the issue is. Any one with any suggestion on this?

Comment: The problem is that your code is absolutely not made to handle part of day, it's built entirely around the idea that a day is the lowest possible granularity. It will need serious reworking to handle half days, and it will modify the function's signature in any case.

Comment: Anthony Rossi, Yes i understood that, I could fetch the Allocation days that is there in  the Leave records.

Answer (score 2):

Let me preface: I haven't used odoo and I don't have the rest of your code to test against so I haven't verified this.

You definitely have a problem here:

```
if leave_type in leaves:
    leaves[leave_type]['number_of_days'] += 1.0
    leaves[leave_type]['number_of_hours'] += working_hours_on_day
else:
    leaves[leave_type] = {
        'name': leave_type,
        'sequence': 5,
        'code': leave_type,
        'number_of_days': 1.0,
        'number_of_hours': working_hours_on_day,
        'contract_id': contract.id,
    }
else:
    #add the input vals to tmp (increment if existing)
    attendances['number_of_days'] += 1.0
    attendances['number_of_hours'] += working_hours_on_day
```

see where you reference leaves and attendances, while those are floats they are only incremented in full days, not calculated based on what fraction of a day you pass. You need to change this to something like:

```
leaves[leave_type]['number_of_days'] += time_off / hours_per_workday # the 1.0 might make sense here depending on if you count time off as an attendance
leaves[leave_type]['number_of_hours'] += time_off
```

and

```
attendances['number_of_days'] += 1.0 - time_off / hours_per_workday
attendances['number_of_hours'] += working_hours_on_day - time_off
```

Obviously the dummy variables I inserted would need to be defined and calculated somewhere.

Additionally, as Anthony Rossi noted in the comments, you generally work in days, not hours. Examples:

```
day_from = datetime.strptime(date_from,"%Y-%m-%d")
day_to = datetime.strptime(date_to,"%Y-%m-%d")
```

notice how you only have YY/MM/DD and no hours.